# Making basic attack animation depending on keypress XNA C#

Tags: c#, animation, xna, 2d, sprite

I've got a 2D rpg-ish thing going on, where I want my character to swing a sword when I press a certain key, the sword swing is made out of 3 sprites.

This is the code I got going on so far:
EDIT: Upon request I've copypasted the entire class in where my attack-animation-code is in.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace RPGJensLomanderV2
{
class Player : Characters
{
    KeyboardState ks;
    Camera camera;
    KeyboardState oldKs;
    int attackTime;
    Vector2 origin = Vector2.Zero;
    bool isAnimationRunning = false;

    public Player(GameScreen gameScreen, Camera camera)
        : base(gameScreen)
    {
        health = 10;
        this.camera = camera;
        direction = Vector2.Zero;
        movementSpeed = 1;
        currentSprite = new Rectangle(229, 30, 14, 16);
    }

    public override void Load(ContentManager content)
    {
        spawnPoint = gameScreen.destSourceRecISE.Where(t => t.Value.X == 78 && t.Value.Y == 26).First().Key;
        position = spawnPoint;
        gameScreen.destSourceRecISE.Remove(spawnPoint);
        base.Load(content);
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        ks = Keyboard.GetState();
        timeSprite += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
        Attack(gameTime);
        attackTime = 0;
        Movement(gameTime);
        camera.Position = position;
        oldKs = ks;
    }

    private void Movement(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) && ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            direction = new Vector2(1, -1);
            directionPointer = 1;
            if (currentSprite.X != 140 && currentSprite.X != 154)
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(140, 30, 14, 16);
            if (timeSprite >= 100)
            {
                if (currentSprite.X == 140)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(154, 30, 14, 16);
                else if (currentSprite.X == 154)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(140, 30, 14, 16);
                timeSprite = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) && ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        {
            direction = new Vector2(1, 1);
            directionPointer = 2;
            if (currentSprite.X != 229 && currentSprite.X != 245)
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(229, 30, 16, 16);
            if (timeSprite >= 100)
            {
                if (currentSprite.X == 229)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(245, 30, 16, 16);
                else if (currentSprite.X == 245)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(229, 30, 16, 16);
                timeSprite = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            direction = new Vector2(-1, -1);
            directionPointer = 1;
            if (currentSprite.X != 140 && currentSprite.X != 154)
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(140, 30, 14, 16);
            if (timeSprite >= 100)
            {
                if (currentSprite.X == 140)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(154, 30, 14, 16);
                else if (currentSprite.X == 154)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(140, 30, 14, 16);
                timeSprite = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        {
            direction = new Vector2(-1, 1);
            directionPointer = 2;
            if (currentSprite.X != 229 && currentSprite.X != 245)
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(229, 30, 16, 16);
            if (timeSprite >= 100)
            {
                if (currentSprite.X == 229)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(245, 30, 16, 16);
                else if (currentSprite.X == 245)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(229, 30, 16, 16);
                timeSprite = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            direction = new Vector2(-1, 0);
            directionPointer = 3;
            if (currentSprite.X != 198 && currentSprite.X != 214)
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(198, 30, 16, 16);
            if (timeSprite >= 100)
            {
                if (currentSprite.X == 198)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(214, 30, 15, 16);
                else if (currentSprite.X == 214)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(198, 30, 16, 16);
                timeSprite = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            direction = new Vector2(1, 0);
            directionPointer = 4;
            if (currentSprite.X != 168 && currentSprite.X != 184)
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(168, 30, 16, 16);
            if (timeSprite >= 100)
            {
                if (currentSprite.X == 168)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(184, 30, 16, 16);
                else if (currentSprite.X == 184)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(168, 30, 16, 16);
                timeSprite = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            direction = new Vector2(0, -1);
            directionPointer = 1;
            if (currentSprite.X != 140 && currentSprite.X != 154)
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(140, 30, 14, 16);
            if (timeSprite >= 100)
            {
                if (currentSprite.X == 140)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(154, 30, 14, 16);
                else if (currentSprite.X == 154)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(140, 30, 14, 16);
                timeSprite = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        {
            direction = new Vector2(0, 1);
            directionPointer = 2;
            if (currentSprite.X != 229 && currentSprite.X != 245)
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(229, 30, 16, 16);
            if (timeSprite >= 100)
            {
                if (currentSprite.X == 229)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(245, 30, 16, 16);
                else if (currentSprite.X == 245)
                    currentSprite = new Rectangle(229, 30, 16, 16);
                timeSprite = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            direction = Vector2.Zero;
            timeSprite = 0;
        }
        position += movementSpeed * direction;
    }

    private void Attack(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) /*&& oldKs.IsKeyUp(Keys.A)*/)
        {
            isAnimationRunning = true;
        }
        while (isAnimationRunning && directionPointer == 1)
        {
            attackTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
            if (attackTime > 1 && attackTime < 100)
            {
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(3, 46, 32, 16);
            }
            if (attackTime < 200 && attackTime > 100)
            {
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(33, 61, 32, 32);
            }
            if (attackTime > 200 && attackTime < 300)
            {
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(61, 65, 16, 32);
            }
            if (attackTime > 300)
            {
                attackTime = 0;
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(140, 30, 14, 16);
                isAnimationRunning = false;
            }
        }
        if (directionPointer == 2 && isAnimationRunning)
        {
            attackTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
            if (attackTime < 100)
            {
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(4, 67, 32, 16);
            }
            else if (attackTime < 200 && attackTime > 100)
            {
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(35, 66, 32, 32);
            }
            else if (attackTime > 200 && attackTime < 300)
            {
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(69, 66, 16, 32);
            }
            else if (attackTime > 300)
            {
                attackTime = 0;
                isAnimationRunning = false;
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(229, 30, 16, 16);
            }
        }
        if (directionPointer == 3 && isAnimationRunning)
        {
            attackTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
            if (attackTime < 100)
            {
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(5, 138, 16, 32);
            }
            else if (attackTime < 200 && attackTime > 100)
            {
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(20, 138, 32, 32);
            }
            else if (attackTime > 200 && attackTime < 300)
            {
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(53, 154, 32, 16);
            }
            else if (attackTime > 300)
            {
                attackTime = 0;
                isAnimationRunning = false;
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(198, 30, 16, 16);
            }
        }
        if (directionPointer == 4 && isAnimationRunning)
        {
            attackTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
            if (attackTime < 100)
            {
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(5, 102, 16, 32);
            }
            else if (attackTime < 200 && attackTime > 100)
            {
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(20, 102, 32, 32);
            }
            else if (attackTime > 200 && attackTime < 300)
            {
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(51, 118, 32, 16);
            }
            else if (attackTime > 300)
            {
                attackTime = 0;
                currentSprite = new Rectangle(168, 30, 16, 16);
                isAnimationRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, currentSprite, Color.White, 0f, origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    }
}
}
```

Right now, it does not go past the first sprite of the attack when I swing, and I am not totally sure how to make it happen. I'd be grateful if someone could give me a tip or the like of how I could make it go through the entire code so that a full swing will be done on the press of a button? Thanks on beforehand!

Comment: if you keep button pressed then it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a global variable

```
bool isAnimationRunning = false;
```

and then change your code like this:

```
if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) && directionPointer == 1 && oldKs.IsKeyUp(Keys.A))
{
    isAnimationRunning = true;
}

if(isAnimationRunning)
{
    attackTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
    if (attackTime > 1 && attackTime < 100)
    {
        currentSprite = new Rectangle(3, 46, 32, 16);
    }
    else if (attackTime < 200 && attackTime > 100)
    {
        currentSprite = new Rectangle(33, 61, 32, 32);
    }
    else if (attackTime > 200 && attackTime < 300)
    {
        currentSprite = new Rectangle(61, 65, 16, 32);
    }
    else if (attackTime > 300)
    {
        attackTime = 0;
        isAnimationRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to say that that works, but it doesn't, weirdly enough. It should. It looks right to me o.o

Comment: Is isAnimationRunning defined globally, or inside a method?

Comment: It is defined globally, and he starts attacking when the button is pressed, so that part Does work. what doesn't is that now my character swings his sword as soon as I stop moving, but freezes at the first attack sprite. So basically, I don't think the code ever reaches the last if-block of code. Tried removing the else's, and tried making a while(isAnimationRunning) instead, did not help.

Comment: Try setting a break point to the last if, and see if it is reached. Probably you need to reset the currentSprite to the default one in the last if?

Comment: The weird thing is that it DOES reach the last if, when I got a while(isAnimationRunning) instead, but the sprites do not change (and they should be)

Comment: Can you provide more code? If possible show the whole class implementing isAnimationRunning, currentSprite, and attackTime.

Comment: You are setting your attackTime to 0 in Update(), that prevents your code from working correctly, since attackTime has just to be reset in Attack() in else if (attackTime > 300)... So remove the line attackTime = 0; from your Update method.